# How to create a sharable url containing dynamic html (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, url-routing, share

What is the best practice to create unique shareable urls for some text lists users create?

It's a single page website with a content div where users create text lists. Once they click share, how can I store those values inside a shareable url so that another user going to that address loads the same list?

I'm using html, js, jquery, php.

**EDIT:** as suggested below i'm already saving the lists on a database (firebase), and each have an unique ID, so I'd need to understand how I can create urls with a list id in it, and how to read the url back.

**EDIT 2:** so this is the code i'm using right now, combining answers from **marzelin** and the **Alchemist Shahed** in my other question about my database structure ([Firebase how to find child knowing its id but not its parent's id (js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782070/firebase-how-to-find-child-knowing-its-id-but-not-its-parents-id-js)):

```
//js inside window load function:
  const keyOfDynamicHtmlItemRef = new URL(window.location).searchParams.get("share")
  if (keyOfDynamicHtmlItemRef) {
    var dynamicHtmlListRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
    // var dynamicHtmlItemRef = dynamicHtmlListRef.child(keyOfDynamicHtmlItemRef);
    // console.log(keyOfDynamicHtmlItemRef);
    // dynamicHtmlItemRef.once("value").then(dynamicHtmlSnap => {
    //   texta.innerHTML = dynamicHtmlSnap.val();
    // });
    dynamicHtmlListRef.once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
     snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        if (data.key == keyOfDynamicHtmlItemRef) {
          myVar = data.c;
          myContentDiv.innerHTML = myVar;
        }
     });
    });
  }
```

and i'm simply trying to manually write the url in the searchbar as a first step, as `https://example.com/?share=<random list id i copied from db>`, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving data and creating shareable link:

```js
document.querySelector(".share").addEventListener("click" => {
  var dynamicHtmlListRef = firebase.database().ref('dynamic_html');
  var dynamicHtmlItemRef = dynamicHtmlListRef.push();
  dynamicHtmlItemRef.set(userCreatedDynamicHtml);
  var keyOfDynamicHtmlItem = dynamicHtmlItemRef.key;
  var linkToDynamicHtmlItem = `${window.location}?share=${keyofDynamicHtmlItem}`;
  alert(`link: ${linkToDynamicHtmlItem}`)
})
```

Showing the dynamic HTML based on query parameters:

```js
const keyOfDynamicHtmlItemRef = new URL(window.location).searchParams.get("share")
if (keyOfDynamicHtmlItemRef) {
  var dynamicHtmlListRef = firebase.database().ref('dynamic_html');
  var dynamicHtmlItemRef = dynamicHtmlListRef.child(keyOfDynamicHtmlItemRef);
  keyOfDynamicHtmlItemRef.once("value").then(dynamicHtmlSnap => {
    document.querySelector(".dynamic-html-mountpoint").innerHTML = dynamicHtmlSnap.val();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i'm looking for i think, my current solution was quite similar, i was creating an url with /#<list_id> but doesn't work. Now i'll try to implement it and i'll update you. I hope the rule read: true on firebase is enough to let anyone (even not auth users) to read the list_id content back.

Comment: I need to parse the list content inside my ids structure you can see here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782070/firebase-how-to-find-child-knowing-its-id-but-not-its-parents-id-js), so i tried to use the code @Alchemist Shahed suggested me over there, but I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: permission_denied at /users: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. (i'll edit showing the code i'm using)

Comment: Solved the error, i had to move the "read": true outside of parent user_id , but it does nothing now

Comment: I was able to retrieve list content setting the url manually in the browser, as a test, i updated the solution in the link i mentioned above. now i try to save and create the link and let you know

Comment: Thanks it all works fine now. Assigning the bounty in 3 hr when it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

So the way I would to this is I would have the users share click trigger a save to database saving all the dynamically generated content into a table.

One of the table values would be a randomly generated unique identifier of some sort that I would use as a query in the url like `https://www.example.org/?share=skd822475`

Then when a user visits the site and that query is in the url id use the unique identifier to look up the database and publish the dynamic content back on the page.

I would also put a half life on the database entry's of say no more than 30 days so that it doesn't clog up the db.

Comment: I'm actually already saving all the lists on firebase, so giving users the ability to share them only if they saved it first, would work perfectly with the idea you mentioned! what i've got a complete void about is how can i create those urls and read them back? thanks

Comment: ok so what you want to do is : in firebase when you post save and all that you get a uniqe id for the content so its this id you want. You then want to grab that unique id and insert it into the url you are going to deliver.  this might also help https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually

Comment: There is no documentation for javascript

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the first question "**How to create urls with a list id in it?**"

The thing is that to answer this one we need to answer the second question first witch is
"**How to read the url back?**"

Consider that you have a php page named "draft". when a user visit `https://www.example.com/draft?listId=an_id` you will get `listId` using php like so `$_GET("listId")` and use that value to retrieve the list data and display the page content.

Now coming back to the first question, if the user share the draft like in social media (ex: facebook) then there is no problem because he will share a link and all his followers and any other user can access it easily. but if the user just save the draft then you will have to change the page url dynamically like this `window.history.pushState(null, null, '/draft?listId=your_newly_created_id');` and so the user will copy the url and do whatever he wnt with it (sharing it in stackoverflow maybe example using jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F2es9/ (you can change the url to look like this using 'htaccess' file))   at the end I would like to tell you that we don't "create" urls.

**Edit**

without using php code (or any other server side code). the difference will be in retrieving the data.
instead of using `$_GET("listId")` you will use `new URL(window.location).searchParams.get("listId")` to get the list id in javascript then using this value you can retrieve data from firebase and display your content

Comment: Thanks for your answer i start to put the puzzle pieces together. Luckly there is no draft thing, what the user shares will remain like that in the url. The problem is that firebase doesn't let users to read data (id's content) from another user, from what i understood it needs some sort of admin queries server side.

Comment: The middle part about the draft is still not clear to me, how can it be that if i create an url using js like so and put the list id inside "?listId=" then php knows what is inside that id automatically? also can't i create a custom https://example.com/#<listid> and then with javascript say if url.indexOf(<listid>) then load stuff from firebase? isn't the same? i guess there's too much back end knowledge involved (i'm not a back end dev at all) so unless a library exists that facilitates things a bit is prob better i give up on this

Comment: @notsure of course you will have to use server side code. When you get  $_GET("listId") in php you will have to retrieve data using this admin querie after all php is a server side language

Comment: @notsure you said that you don't understand how php knows what is inside the id automatically. It's not automatically php can know that value and it's equal to  $_GET("listId") so you will use  $_GET("listId") to retrieve data from firebase. But you should follow some php tutorial

Comment: @notsure lastly you can't use javascript to retrieve data from firebase you need to use a server side language like php

Comment: You can use client side code to read and write on firebase, cause it has a simple panel for rules to control access. Im using firebase exactly because i'd like to avoid php/mysql and back end stuff, so if i find a js solution i prefer that.

Comment: @notsure if you use javascript in the front-end to retrieve data or update data. anyone will be able to hack your database easily. if you still want to use just javascript check my edited post

Comment: I'm not a back end dev but i know about that, firebase works front-end, setting rules prevent database from being hacked https://firebase.com