# Firebase how to find child knowing its id but not its parent's id (js)

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, snapshot

I have a firebase realtime database (not cloud) structure like:

```
users
  kasdf872ajsda   //user id
     auiiq6d182g1   //list id
        c: <mycontent>   //list content
```

i know the list id (in this case `auiiq6d182g1`) and i want to retrieve `<mycontent>`, but i don't know the user id `kasdf872ajsda` , because what i'm going to retrieve is probably not from the user currently using the website (and i'm not setting any database rules for "read" in fact, only for "write" is that correct?).

What i'm doing right now is this (not working):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('users');
ref.child(listID).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  var snap = snapshot.val();
  myContent = snap.c;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, if someone should encounter the same issue:

```
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        snap = data.child(<YOUR_LIST_ID>).child('c').val();
        if (snap != null){
          myContent = snap;
        }
      });
});
```

also `ref` contrary to what everyone says has to be:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('users');
```

this doesn't work:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your reference to users first: `var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');`

Then loop through:

```
ref.once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
   snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
      if (data.key == <YOUR_LIST_ID>) {
         //you can access data.c here...
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: permission_denied at /users: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. (weird because in rules i've set "read" : true

Comment: You have to double check your firebase configuration. Do you have your URL set correctly? Are you sure your rules look like this:
`{
    "rules": {    
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}`

Comment: Yes firebase is working correctly, saves stuff, fetches stuff etc. read rule is set to true, write rule is set to:  ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"

Comment: I solved the error, the "read": true in the rules had to be one step above, outside the $user_id subcategory, but it does nothing now anyway

Comment: I solved it, posted the solution. Gave you a thumbs up since you put me on the right path. thanks